# Some ways to affect manta flow with rigid body

Tags: fluid-simulation

While making a lot of fluid simulations, I wondered why Flip Solver, Realflow with flip, can interact with rigid bodies, and mantaflow no. Are there some ways to affect this? Thanks in advance.